# Jsreports fails to initialize, throwing "Error: Unsupported store provider fs"

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsreport

I am just trying to test out using jsreport-core in node and am having trouble getting it to initialize here is my code:

```
  const jsReport = require('jsreport-core')({
        loadConfig: false,
        dataDirectory: path.join(__dirname, 'data'),
        blobStorage: 'fileSystem',
        connectionString: { 'name': 'fs' }
    });
    jsReport.use(require('jsreport-handlebars'));
    jsReport.use(require('jsreport-phantom-pdf'));
    jsReport.use(require('jsreport-templates'));
    jsReport.use(require('jsreport-fs-store'));
    jsReport.init();
```

And then for some reason is is having trouble using jsreport-fs-store.

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Unsupported store provider fs
    at module.exports.DocumentStore.init (jsReportTest/node_modules/jsreport-core/lib/store/documentStore.js:37:11)
```

If anyone could help me out and tell me what I'm missing it would be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to **create an instance of each jsreport extension** when using `jsreport.use`. here is the right way to use `jsreport.use` calls

```
const jsReport = require('jsreport-core')({
        loadConfig: false,
        dataDirectory: path.join(__dirname, 'data'),
        blobStorage: 'fileSystem',
        connectionString: { 'name': 'fs' }
    });
    jsReport.use(require('jsreport-handlebars')());
    // you can also use jsReport.use(require('jsreport-handlebars')({//options here..})) if you need to pass specific options to the extension used
    jsReport.use(require('jsreport-phantom-pdf')());
    jsReport.use(require('jsreport-templates')());
    jsReport.use(require('jsreport-fs-store')());

    jsReport.init().then(function () {
      console.log('jsreport started')
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.error('Error while starting jsreport:')
      console.error(err)
    });
```

Comment: Awesome don't know how I missed that. Thank you very much